# Kettle or PDI: share same DB connection between different steps

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I've multiple DB connections in a Kettle (Pentaho Data Integration) trasformation.

There are some lookup steps and a table output steps.
They must use the same DB connection.

I'm searching a way to change the DB connection in a step and automatically change the connection also in the other steps.
Is it possible?

I know that i can use variable readed from parameters inside the connection definition, but i'm searching a sort of GUI way.

Answer (score 1):

First implementation use jdbc connection pool. Set pool size same as number of steps in transformation demand connections to DB.
[image: JDBC Connection Pool]

Another case to define separate connection for each step. It is much easier if you use jndi preconfigured in $KETTLE_HOME/simple-jndi/jdbc.properties

For example on image underneath two variables point on master and slave connection. This will allow you to choose appropriate connection.

[image: Separate connections]

How to configure jndi in Pentahoo Kettle
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/.03+Database+Connections